for loop only printing first instance when i know for a fact there are 48
import json

f = open('messages_1.json')
data = json.load(f)
d = 'call_duration'
calls = None

for i in data['messages']:
    if d in i:
        calls = i
        break
print(calls)

Im trying to just get call logs but the code is only returning the first on in the list of dictionaries, if i remove the break statement it returns a different instance but again, only 1 is returned.

You're breaking out of the loop when you find the first matching element of the list.

print(calls) is not in the loop. So it just prints the last value of calls. Put it in the loop to see all of them.

i realize im breaking out of it after the first match, but i dont know how to get it to continue, if i remove the break statement it still only prints 1 instance, but a different one

Or make calls a list and append to it.

Short version: print('\n'.join(i for i in data['messages'] if d in i))
